# ActiveRecord::Base.store automatic typecasting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, casting, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Is there a way to automatically typecast values that are stored using ActiveRecord::Base.store?

Take this totally impractical example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :settings, accessors: [ :age ]
end

user = User.new(age: '10')
user.age # => '10'
```

I know I can just override the reader method for age to convert it to an integer, but I was curious if there was an undocumented way of doing it.

Trying to avoid this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :settings, accessors: [ :age ]

  def age
    settings[:age].to_i
  end
end

user = User.new(age: '10')
user.age # => 10
```

**Update**

Looking for something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :settings, accessors: {:age => :to_i}
end
```

Or:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :settings, accessors: {:age => Integer}
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Rails 3.2.7 there is not a way to automatically typecast values. I'll update this question if I ever come across a way to do it :/

Answer (score 1):

I know of two ways to do it. One of them you convert it every time it is set. The other you convert it only when you save it to the database.

Option one: custom setter

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  # public method
  def age=(age)
    self.settings[:age] = age.to_i
  end

  ...

end
```

In console:

```
$ user.age = '12'     # => "12"
$ user.age            # => 12
$ user.age.class      # => Fixnum
$ user = User.new age: '5'
$ user.age.class      # => Fixnum
```

Option two: before_save call (or different before call)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :age_to_int

  ...

  private

    def age_to_int
      # uncomment the if statement to avoid age being set to 0
      # if you create a user without an age
      self.age = self.age.to_i # if self.age 
    end

end
```

In console

```
$ user = User.new(age: '10')
$ user.save
$ user.age            # => 10
$ user.age.class      # => Fixnum
```

Shortcoming of option two:

```
$ user.age = '12'
$ user.age            # => "12"
```

I'd use the custom setter if I were you. If you want a default value independent of the database column (which is a string), use a before_save in addition to the setter.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this isn't quite what I was looking for. I was hoping there was something built into the DSL method that would allow me to set defaults.

Comment: I think that goes against the point of a hash you can put anything into... but look around n good luck

Comment: Agreed, and it's a total abuse of ActiveRecord and relational databases. It was more of a curiosity thing I guess.

Comment: Yeah, I like the idea - i didnt know it existed. If you need a typed column you should probably just make an age column thats an integer. Then again 3 lines of code for a setter is not too horrible

Comment: hopefully someone comes along and enlightens us :)

Answer (score 1):

[Storext](https://github.com/G5/storext) adds type-casting and other features on top of `ActiveRecord::Store.store_accessor`.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to chain the store accessor methods rather than override them because the methods created by these magic incantations are never as simple as you'd think:

```
define_method(key) do
  send("#{store_attribute}=", {}) unless send(store_attribute).is_a?(Hash)
  send(store_attribute)[key]
end
```

So, in the case of an integer for example I'd do this:

```
def age_with_typecasting
  ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter::Column.value_to_integer(age_without_typecasting)
end

alias_method_chain :age, :typecasting
```

Again, it's not built in, but it'll do the trick. It also utilises your databases connection adapter to do the conversion from the string that is stored in the database to what you want the value type to be. Change the adapter depending on the database you use.

Answer (score 0):

We didn't find any undocumented way of doing it, but even if you did, it's not recommended to rely your code on Rails private methods.

Here's the way we're doing it in Rails 5.2 using a supported API. Assuming you have a rate model and want to store daily rates in a single database column named :rate_per_day (we're using MySQL so the type of the column is TEXT):

```
class Rate < ApplicationRecord

  DAILY_RATES = [
    :monday_rate,
    :tuesday_rate,
    :wednesday_rate,
    :thursday_rate,
    :friday_rate,
    :saturday_rate,
    :sunday_rate,
  ]

  store :rate_per_day, accessors: DAILY_RATES, coder: JSON

  DAILY_RATES.each do |method|

    define_method(method) do
      super().try(:to_i)
    end

    define_method("#{method}=") do |value|
      super(value.try(:to_i))
    end

  end
```

This is oficially supported. Read the Overwriting default accessors in https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html.

By the way, we investigated using the new Attributes API, because that supports automatic typecasting, but couldn't find a way of storing all the data in a single column unless we created a custom type object.

Answer (score 0):

activerecord-typedstore works pretty well for this and allows you to prevent null and blank values:

https://github.com/byroot/activerecord-typedstore